# How to display text in multiple lines in cloned asp:textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a `div` and I have created its clone on a button click. I changed the `id` of the cloned object and the textbox inside it. Now I want to add text in the cloned textbox. How can I add text into an `asp:textbox` in multiple lines?

The problem I am getting is, if I use `textmode=multiline`, nothing is being displayed and if I remove `textmode=multiline` then text is displaying in the same line.

Please find below my code.

```js
var cloneCount = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        cloneCount = cloneCount + 1;
        var clone = $("#dynamicDiv").clone(true);
        clone.show();
        clone.find('input[type="text"]').attr('id', 'textbox' + cloneCount);
        clone.find('input[type="text"]').val("yasir \r\n yasir");
        clone.css('display', 'inline-block');
        clone.attr('id', 'dynamicDiv' + cloneCount).insertAfter("#dynamicDiv");
        clone.appendTo("#divHolderFirstModule");
    });
});

$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.removeDiv', function () {
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<div ID="dynamicDivFirstModule"  >
    <%--  Dynamic Div--%>
        <div id="dynamicDiv" style="display:none; border:solid;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1" rowspan="2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" style="overflow:auto;" Height="102px" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td id="hoverHere">
                        <asp:Label ID="Hovar" runat="server" Text="?"></asp:Label>
                        <p id="hover" class="masterTooltip" onmouseover="Hover();">?</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="removeDiv"/>      
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <%--  Dynamic Div--%>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess: `textmode=multiline` will render as `textarea` (not `input type=text`), so try to change your js code similar to: `clone.find('textarea').attr('id', 'textbox' + cloneCount);`.